# gpg2 - no option to select aes block cipher and outdated use agent?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, gnupg

With OpenSSL, I can select a what type of block cipher to use for encrypting a file.

For example, if I want to encrypt a file with AES256 CBC block cipher mode:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:MYPASSWORD -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc
```

In gpg2, I try to encrypt a file with the following:

```
gpg2 --cipher-algo AES256 -a --no-use-agent --passphrase MYPASSWORD -c secrets.txt
```

There are two problems I could get some help with:

- There is no option to specify what cipher block to use. What if I want AES256 CTR or XTS instead of CBC? What cipher block does `--cipher-algo AES256` use and how do I specify something specific?
- The command completely fails if I don't enter the passphrase in the gnu password agent (I'm trying to supply the passphrase in the command with `--passphrase` and `--no-use-agent`, for possible automation on a trusted machine):

  gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect

  gpg: problem with the agent: Invalid card

  gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled

  gpg: symmetric encryption of `secrets.txt' failed: Operation cancelled

Comment: Note that recent GnuPG versions use the agent to perform crypto operations; you cannot disable it.

Comment: @grawity So it's not possible to automate gpg2 enc/dec operations? It seems like I have to manually type in my passphrase into the agent.

Comment: Man page... With gpg2 you must use the `--batch` option instead of `--no-use-agent`.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what you're trying to achieve. I can tell it's some kind of automation but not really sure about your scenario

Answer (score 1):

### Cypher Mode

OpenPGP enforces one given mode, a [modified CBC mode as defined in RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9). You cannot change it to something else.

### GPG agent

As already noted by @grawity in the comments, more recent versions of GnuPG 2 extracted some cryptographic functions to the agent, so the passphrase and private key don't leave this smaller program with lower probability for vulnerabilities.

I guess that using [`gpg-preset-passphrase`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html#gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase) ([documentation for GnuPG 2.1](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html#gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase)) to set the passphrase programatically is the way to go for batch operation in GnuPG 2. An alternative might be to use the [`--passphrase[-fd, file]](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html#index-passphrase_002dfd-393) options which still seem to be available in GnuPG 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of supported ciphers you can use `gpg2 --version`. On my machine I get the following output:

Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256

I don't see a way to change to CTR or XTS, though.

I also don't see the option to specify passphrase in the command line but maybe you could try encrypting with a secret key instead of a passphrase.

Comment: I thought the secret key was generated from the passphrase?

Comment: @vcipq: No; merely encrypted using it.